# How can I get the attributes of a fill_between() region from a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have included some simple code to plot some data with a fitted line and a shaded confidence interval. I would like to add a "set preferences" dialog to allow the user to change the data label and marker, the line label and line attributes, and the confidence interval's edge color, fill color, and alpha value. I can use `for line in ax.axes.get_lines()` to get the labels and attributes of the current marker and line, but I don't know how to get the name and attributes of the confidence interval. I know I could just keep track of the changes, but I would like to learn how to get this information from the plot itself (if possible).

```
import sys
import scipy.optimize
import numpy
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class MatplotlibFigure(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    def plot(self):
        self.figure.clf()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
       
        x = [5.357, 5.457, 5.797, 5.936, 6.161, 6.697, 6.731, 6.775, 8.442, 9.769, 9.861]
        y = [0.376, 0.489, 0.874, 1.049, 1.327, 2.054, 2.077, 2.138, 4.744, 7.068, 7.104]

        x = numpy.array(x)
        y = numpy.array(y)

        func = lambda x, a, b: a * x + b 

        best_fit_ab, covar = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y)
        sigma_ab = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diagonal(covar))

        hires_x = numpy.linspace(4, 12, 100)
        bound_upper = func(hires_x, *(best_fit_ab + sigma_ab))
        bound_lower = func(hires_x, *(best_fit_ab - sigma_ab))

        ax.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', markersize = 3.5, markeredgewidth = 0.75, markeredgecolor = 'black', fillstyle = 'none', linestyle = 'none', color = 'black', label = 'Data')
        ax.plot(hires_x, func(hires_x, *best_fit_ab), linestyle = '-', label = 'Fit')
        ax.fill_between(hires_x, bound_lower, bound_upper, aa = True, alpha = 0.3, edgecolor = 'darkorange', facecolor = 'orange', label = 'CI')

        self.canvas.draw_idle()

        for line in ax.axes.get_lines():
            print('label: ' + line.get_label())
            print('marker: ' + line.get_marker())
            print('line style: ' + line.get_linestyle())
            print('line width: ' + format(line.get_linewidth()))
            print('line color: ' + line.get_color())
            print('line alpha: ' + format(line.get_alpha()))
            print('line zorder: ' + format(line.get_zorder()))
            print('----------------')

class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.makeUI()

    def makeUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
        self._widget = MyWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._widget)
        self.show()

class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        btn_plot_data = QPushButton('Plot data')
        btn_plot_data.clicked.connect(self.plot_data)

        self.figure = MatplotlibFigure()

        self.layout.addWidget(btn_plot_data)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.figure)

    def plot_data(self):
        self.figure.plot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The easiest way is to grab the element that contains the fill polygon via `fill_element = ax.fill_between(....)` when it is plotted.  Afterwards, you can do `fill_element.set_color('pink')` and `fill_element.set_alpha(0.2)`.  You can do something similar for `line1, = ax.plot(...)` (note the extra comma, needed because `plot` returns a tuple, as it could draw multiple curves in one go).  This is recommended instead of `ax.axes.get_lines()`, as such approach will keep on working as you add more stuff to the plots.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to Johan C. By naming the different elements, I can query the attributes for each. For example `fill_element.get_label()`. There is, however, a slight complication for getting the edge and face colors of fill_element, but it is easily remedied. See the final completed code below.

```
import sys
import scipy.optimize
import numpy
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class MatplotlibFigure(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    def plot(self):
        self.figure.clf()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
       
        x = [5.357, 5.457, 5.797, 5.936, 6.161, 6.697, 6.731, 6.775, 8.442, 9.769, 9.861]
        y = [0.376, 0.489, 0.874, 1.049, 1.327, 2.054, 2.077, 2.138, 4.744, 7.068, 7.104]

        x = numpy.array(x)
        y = numpy.array(y)

        func = lambda x, a, b: a * x + b 

        best_fit_ab, covar = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y)
        sigma_ab = numpy.sqrt(numpy.diagonal(covar))

        hires_x = numpy.linspace(4, 12, 100)
        bound_upper = func(hires_x, *(best_fit_ab + sigma_ab))
        bound_lower = func(hires_x, *(best_fit_ab - sigma_ab))

        line1, = ax.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', markersize = 3.5, markeredgewidth = 0.75, markeredgecolor = 'black', fillstyle = 'none', linestyle = 'none', color = 'black', label = 'Data')
        line2, = ax.plot(hires_x, func(hires_x, *best_fit_ab), linestyle = '-', label = 'Fit')
        fill_element = ax.fill_between(hires_x, bound_lower, bound_upper, aa = True, alpha = 0.3, edgecolor = 'darkorange', facecolor = 'orange', label = 'CI')

        self.canvas.draw_idle()

        print('--------------------')
        print('line 1')
        print('label: ' + line1.get_label())
        print('marker: ' + line1.get_marker())
        print('line style: ' + line1.get_linestyle())
        print('line width: ' + format(line1.get_linewidth()))
        print('line color: ' + line1.get_color())
        print('line alpha: ' + format(line1.get_alpha()))
        print('line zorder: ' + format(line1.get_zorder()))
        print('--------------------')
        print('line 2')
        print('label: ' + line2.get_label())
        print('marker: ' + line2.get_marker())
        print('line style: ' + line2.get_linestyle())
        print('line width: ' + format(line2.get_linewidth()))
        print('line color: ' + line2.get_color())
        print('line alpha: ' + format(line2.get_alpha()))
        print('line zorder: ' + format(line2.get_zorder()))
        print('--------------------')
        print('confidence interval')
        print('label: ' + fill_element.get_label())
        print('edge color: ' + matplotlib.colors.to_hex(fill_element.get_edgecolor()[0], keep_alpha = False))
        print('face color: ' + matplotlib.colors.to_hex(fill_element.get_facecolor()[0], keep_alpha = False))
        print('alpha: ' + format(fill_element.get_alpha()))
        print('zorder: ' + format(fill_element.get_zorder()))
        print('--------------------')

class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.makeUI()

    def makeUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
        self._widget = MyWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._widget)
        self.show()

class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        btn_plot_data = QPushButton('Plot data')
        btn_plot_data.clicked.connect(self.plot_data)

        self.figure = MatplotlibFigure()

        self.layout.addWidget(btn_plot_data)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.figure)

    def plot_data(self):
        self.figure.plot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```